# In Django, how do I write a url.py where users/self/ is the same as users/<pk>/, where <pk> is your logged in user pk?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-authentication, django-users

I am trying to write a `url.py` where I have a simple view for `users`

```
urlpatterns = patterns( 'doors.view',
    url( r'^users/$'            , 'users_list'  , name = 'users_list'   ),
    url( r'^users/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'users_detail', name = 'users_detail' ),
    url( r'^users/self/$'       , # do some sort of redirect here       ),
)
```

The problem with the redirect is I don't know the `pk` of the logged in user in `url.py`. In `view.py`, I would obviously do a `@login_required` to be able to access `users/self/`.

Maybe I am doing this wrong way? What do you guys suggest I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion (not sure if it's the easiest one) would be to create a new view, where you can grab the user's pk and then call the `users_detail` view:

```
@login_required
def self_detail(request):
    return users_detail(request, request.user.pk)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also do the following in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns( 'doors.view',
    url( r'^users/$'            , 'users_list'  , name = 'users_list'   ),
    url( r'^users/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'users_detail', name = 'users_detail' ),
    url( r'^users/self/$'       , 'users_detail', {'pk'='self'}       ),
)
```

And then in views.py:

```
if pk == 'self':
    user = request.user
else:
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a view that invokes `user_detail()` with the value from `request.user.pk`.