# How do I redirect a url using DetailView class in Django?

Tags: django, django-urls

Before I decide to use `DetailView`, I had a url redirect using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849546/in-django-how-do-i-write-a-url-py-where-users-self-is-the-same-as-users-pk).

Now that I am using `DetailView` how do I achieve the same redirect? The `name` has to be the same since I am using that for `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in `settings.py`.

Here is what part of the `urls.py` looks like

```
urlpatterns = patterns( 'doors.views',
    url(
        r'^users/$',
        ListView.as_view(
            model = User,
            template_name = 'doors/users/list.html'
        ),
    ),
    url(
        r'^users/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        DetailView.as_view(
            model = User,
            template_name = 'doors/users/detail.html'
        ),
        name = 'users_detail'
    ),
    url( r'^users/self/$', # do some kind of redirect 'users_self_detail', name = 'users_self_detail' ),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's not call this *redirecting*, because that gets confused with HTTP redirects. Let's just say we want the views to behave the same, ie they should end up in the same code & template. This is where I'd subclass `DetailView` myself. Something like:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'doors/users/detail.html'

class SelfUserDetailView(UserDetailView):
    def get_object(self):
       return self.request.user
```

Then in `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from myapp.views import UserDetailView, SelfUserDetailView
url(r'^users/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='users_detail'),
url(r'^users/self/$', login_required(SelfUserDetailView.as_view()), name='users_self_detail'),
```

Comment: Should I subclass `DetailView` in `urls.py` since I am already importing `DetailView` there?

Comment: Personally I put subclasses in my app `views.py`, similar to when you write your own function-based views. Otherwise your `urls.py` will get huge — we have well over 100 custom class-based views on the site I work on right now.

Comment: What about putting `@login_required` on top of `class SelfUserDetailView`? Any particular reason why you put in the `urls.py`?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the decorators have been updated to work for class-based views, so I avoid that. (This may just be because I was using things before 1.3 settled.)

Comment: Oh oops, that's right `@login_required` is for methods, not classes.

Comment: Django 1.9 introduced the [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) class that is equivalent to the login_required method/function.

Answer (score 3):

[Check the docs out for decorating urls when using class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-class-based-views)

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
urlpatterns = patterns( 'doors.views',
    url(r'^users/$',login_required(ListView.as_view(model = User,template_name = 'doors/users/list.html')),
    ...
),
```

Answer (score 0):

These are 2 ways to do it in Django 2.
You can create view and define template path in

1) Create **view in url file** and define path there

```
from django.urls import  path
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from crm.models import Organisation

urlpatterns = [
    path('org/<int:pk>', DetailView.as_view(model=Organisation, 
template_name = 'crm/org/org_detail_main.html'))
```

2) Create separate view in views and define explicit template there

So here is **urls**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from crm.views import OrganisationDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('org/<int:pk>',OrganisationDetailView.as_view(), 
    name='organisation_detail')
```

And **views**

```
from .models import Activity, Organisation
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView


class OrganisationDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Organisation
    template_name = 'crm/org/org_detail_main.html'
```